# Nested conditions in Bash (if [[...)

Tags: bash, if-statement, nested, conditional-statements, square-bracket

I have several questions I would like to be answered since I'm not a Bash expert so far... There are several conditions I need to check before performing a specific task, but some of them are related and cannot be detached : I would like the following statement to be checked :

```
if ((1 OR 2) AND (3 OR 4))
   then
      blabla...
fi
```

I made this so far,

```
if [[ "[ `echo "$5" | cut -c 1-2` -lt 0 || `echo "$5" | cut -c 1-2` -gt 23 ]" && "[ `echo "$5" | cut -c 4-5` -lt 0 || `echo "$5" | cut -c 4-5` -gt 23 ]" ]]
   then
      echo "La plage horaire indiquée n'est pas valide ! Format = HH-HH"
      exit 3
fi
```

and it works properly. I have the feeling that there's something much easier that can be done in order to perform this check, but I cannot see how...

And second thing, in the code I wrote above, you can see this :

```
"[ `echo "$5" | cut -c 1-2` -lt 0 || `echo "$5" | cut -c 1-2` -gt 23 ]"
```

The simple square-bracket corresponds to the test function, right ? So why is it properly called when putting double-quotes ? I understand I could not put any backquote there, it would not make any sense with my echo "$5"... thing, but double-quotes are supposed to replace special characters such as $ and prevent from ignoring single spaces, so why is it replacing the [ character ? Is it considered as one of these special characters ?

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't repeat yourself:

```
a=$(echo "$5" | cut -c 1-2)
b=$(echo "$5" | cut -c 4-5)
```

or use bash parameter expansion syntax:

```
a=${5:0:2}
b=%{5:3:2}
```

And you can use arithmetic substitution:

```
if (( a < 0 || a > 23)) && (( b < 0 || b > 23 )); then
      echo "La plage horaire indiquée n'est pas valide ! Format = HH-HH"
      exit 3
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

From `help [[`:

> ```
>  ( EXPRESSION )   Returns the value of EXPRESSION
> ```

Comment: Hmmm... Weird, I'm pretty sure I tried that syntax before and I got an error, but it works now... I must have changed something unrelated to this in the meantime.
Thank you for your answer, I guess there's nothing more I can do to get this expression simpler, even if you highlighted an interesting point (I won't be calling the test operator [ anymore in my expression, maybe it'll cost less ressources...) !